# [Flutter_blue]Characteristic.write([0x0,0x0],false) gives me "write_characteristic_error, service could not be located on the device"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

Error caused on Android device (Oneplus 7 pro) with the newest soft I can install here.  I'm sure that service with that id is located in my device, because it was discovered by flutter_blue before it was called.

I have no idea what's going on with that. Part of code which has meaning here:

```
var startVibrating = [0x00, 0xC0, 0x45, 0x22, 0x01, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3];
BluetoothService btVibrations;
BluetoothCharacteristic vibChar;

//here iam getting interested service "starting vibrations" in my device.
void listServices() async {
    List<BluetoothService> services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) async {

      if (service.uuid.toString() == "daebb240-b041-11e4-9e45-0002a5d5c51b") {
        btVibrations = service;
        var characteristics = service.characteristics;
        for (BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
          try {
            if (c.uuid.toString() == "e16c6e20-b041-11e4-a4c3-0002a5d5c51b") {
              //c.write(startVibrating, withoutResponse: true);

              vibChar = c;
              print("UUID val added FIRST: \n\n\n");
              print(c.uuid);
            }
          } on Exception {
            print("error");
          }
        }
      }
    });

  }

 void _startVibrating() async {
    // print(await widget.device.canSendWriteWithoutResponse);
    try {
      widget.device.connect();
    } on Exception {}

    print("device: " + vibChar.deviceId.id);


    vibChar.write(startVibrating, withoutResponse: true);

    await vibChar.write(startVibrating, withoutResponse: true);

    //await vibChar.read();
  }


... blah blah blah rest of long code...

 onPressed: _startVibrating,

... /blah blah blah ...
```

I tried to do that with, and without "Response", tried (as you can see) to be sure that device is connected. I'm sure that variables btVibrations and vibChar aren't nulls.

My idea is it can be caused because flutter_blue still looking for services (I had other error included with that), but I can't find method to dispose that.